# Django-tastypie: how to ModelResource programmatically?

Tags: python, django, backbone.js, tastypie

I have created a number of Django-tastypie resource definitions in resources.py. Most of them will be created by posting from javascript side (backbone-tastypie), but some of them I would like to be able to create right from python code/django views.
The reason for this is that object creation logic should be kept in one place, as well as authorization params.

Is there some neat way to create TastyPie ModelResource inside Python code? (may be making a "post" with "Requests" module?).

Comment: May be Resource.build_bundle() method is a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, your usecase is described in tastypie cookbook: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views